# Scatter in matplotlib shows a vertical line of dots in the center of the chart instead of above the corresponding X axis values

Tags: python, datetime, matplotlib, charts, scatter-plot

The app I am writing parses data in a CSV of datetimes and temperature observation pairs to the same time in another city then writes a report and a scatter chart.  Everything works, except, the scatter chart is showing a vertical line of dots beginning at the center of the x axis, instead of a dot above each listed date on the x axis.

This is the code around my application of matplotlib.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as pp
.
.
.
# Code that imports the CSV, changes the times to the other city ....
.
.
.

paris_stamps = [] # This list is a list of datetimes that compose the X axis

i = 0
while i < len(parsedObservations):
  paris_stamps.append(parsedObservations[i][1])
  i += 1

observed_values = [] # these are the temperatures that go on the X axis
i = 0
while i < len(parsedObservations): 
  observed_values.append(parsedObservations[i][0])
  i += 1

# the code below is the interaction with matplotlib 

paris_stamps = [pandas.to_datetime(d) for d in paris_stamps] # sanitize the string datetimes to a format matplotlib will accept

pp.scatter(x = paris_stamps,y = observed_values, s = 500, c='blue')
pp.show()
```

When I run this, I get this for a chart:[Chart with a vertical line of dots instead of a horizontal series of dots above each of the x axis values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c7s3J.jpg)

- How do I get matplotlib scatter plot to format with a real X,Y pairing chart in this context?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to give you what you want exactly without your data. Essentially, you are trying to plot categorical data on a scatter plot, which is designed for numerical data. You could use numerical data, `range(0, len(observed_values))`, to finish the plot first. Then you can change tick labels to corresponding categories as you want. Hopefully, the following is close to what you want:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

observed_values = [6, 3, 1, 5, 2, 4]
paris_stamps = ['2017-04', '2017-05', '2017-06', '2017-07', '2017-08', '2017-09']
plt.scatter(range(0, len(observed_values)), observed_values)
plt.xticks(range(0, len(observed_values)), paris_stamps)
plt.show()
```

You can get this:
[image]

Comment: Thank you for this answer. This makes sense.